# Interactive PDF button that exports PDF to JPG

Tags: javascript, pdf, action, interactive, acrobat

I am trying to create a button in Adobe Acrobat that when clicked, exports the PDF (only one page) to JPG. I had a work around using actions (save as action). But this only works on Adobe Acrobat. The end user will be using PDF X-Change where save as won't show JPG as a file format option.

On PDF x-change you can export to image, so I was wondering if this could be done through Javascript action on a button? I am a graphic designer, so I have small coding knowledge and not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think, but could be proved wrong, that placing JavaScript actions to control UserInterface is available without the SDK version. So what is possible in user versions are Macros, however again As far as I know, they dont affect the main functions like Export, except to provide command variables like page number or output folder.

What is easiest is to Launch Application with page number and for images I recommend either Xpdf utilities "pdftopng" (for PDF working PNG is most relevant pixel format) or if  you must have more powerful options then mutools draw png (or jpg) or other formats.

[image]

You need to verify your position re licensing since neither PDF X-Change nor the others are freeware, they are licensed Open Source Software.

But there is an even simpler no cost solution, than that, so save a custom setting profile for image exports (show them how to import so its the default) and move a custom icon to the first toolbar position like this

[image]

When the user has a page in focus (selected) they click the button and the current page then OK, thus no need for any scripting.

[image]